# Monitor Resolution

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have a Compaq Evo N600c laptop.  This document says the max resolution of my monitor is higher than the 1024x768 it currently is set at.

http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/hp-compaq-evo-n600c/1707-3121_7-7345332.html

I am running Windows 7 32-bit.  If I right-click on my desktop and go to screen resolution, it will let my go higher than 1024x768.  If I try a higher resolution, it keeps my screen the same size, but gives me a larger "virtual desktop".  I believe it is Windows not knowing that my monitor goes higher than 1024x768.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [manufacturer's website](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/10886_div/10886_div.HTML) you can have

> 14.1-inch color TFT SXGA+ with 1400 x 1050 resolution (up to 16.7M colors
>   internal)
>
> or
>
> 14.1-inch color TFT XGA with 1024 x 768 resolution (up to 16.7M colors
>   internal)

Perhaps you have the version that will only support 1024 x 768.

The other option is to make sure you have the correct video driver installed.